# How to check if a classifier belongs to sklearn.tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Suppose, I have a trained model, and I would like to check whether the model is a tree-based classifier. What is the best way to determine it?

e.g. I'm looking for something following:

```
import sklearn
from imaginarypackage import listmodules
if type(clf).__name__ in listmodules(sklearn.tree)
```

I have tried:

```
>>> import pkgutil
>>> 'DecisionTreeClassifier' in pkgutil.iter_modules(["sklearn.tree"])
>>> False
```

I understand not all the tree-based models (e.g. RandomForest) are under skelarn.tree. Hence, having a generic solution will be of very much help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570845/10473393) is what you're looking for, just generically speaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Check type of tree model

As @Alexander Santos suggests, you can use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570802/python-check-if-object-is-instance-of-any-class-from-a-certain-module/14570845#14570845) to check which module your class belongs to. As far as I can tell, the tree based models are either a part of `sklearn.tree` or `sklearn.ensemble._tree` modules.

```py
# Method 1: check if object type has __module__ attribute
module = getattr(clf, '__module__', '')

if module.startswith('sklearn.tree') or module.startswith('sklearn.ensemble._tree'):
    print("clf is a tree model")
```

Alternatively, a less python-esque method is to convert the `type` to a string and perform the same comparison.

```py
# Method 2: convert type to string
type_ = str(type(clf))

if "sklearn.tree" in type_ or "sklearn.ensemble._tree" in type_:
    print("Clf is probably a tree model")
```

You can obviously rewrite this more efficiently if you need to test against many more than just two modules.

##### Alternative 'hack'

By inspecting the methods of `DecisionTree`, `RandomForest` and `ExtraTrees` regressor and classifiers using `dir(clf)`, it appears all the models you want to test for have methods such as:

- `min_samples_leaf`
- `min_weight_fraction_leaf`
- `max_leaf_nodes`

So if you really needed one check to validate your model type, you can inspect the model's methods:

```py
attributes = dir(clf)

check_for_list = ['min_samples_leaf', 'min_weight_fraction_leaf', 'max_leaf_nodes']

verdict = False
for check in check_for_list:
    if check in attributes:
        verdict = True
        break

if verdict:
    print("clf is probably a tree-based model.")
```